# unique answer to rref

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Solve the matrix. The given matrix is matrix $Q$. I performed RREF and got $C$.

Would $C$ yield a unique solution, or are there more steps to the problem?

$$
Q = \begin{pmatrix} 
1&1&1&-2&3\\
2&1&3&2&9\\
0&-1&1&6&3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&2&4&6\\
0&1&-1&-6&-3\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: What does "Solve the matrix" mean? Do you mean put the matrix into RREF?

Comment: No unique answer. Five variables, two linear restrictions.

Comment: It originally said to solve the system of linear equations. I put it in matrix form to make it easier.

Comment: You put it in matrix form to make it more confusing. A system of equations has a left side, and a right side. Where's the right side in your system? Are we to assume there's all zeros on the right side? Anyway, a solution of a system of equations should look like $x_1={\rm\ some\ stuff}$, $x_2={\rm\ some\ other\ stuff}$, and so on, but all you have written is a matrix, so, yes you have lots more steps to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $Q$ represents the system
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 - 2x_4 &= 3 \\
2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3 + 2x_4 &= 9\\
-x_2 + x_3 + 6x_4 &= 3
\end{align}
as it's common practice in most undergrad level linear algebra texts to adjoin the RHS to the right of the coefficient matrix for solving a system by Gaussian elimination (i.e. row reduction).

The RREF being $C$ tells us that
\begin{align}
x_1 + 2x_3 + 4x_4 &= 6 \\
x_2 - x_3 - 6x_4 &= -3
\end{align}

We can solve for the leading variable in each equation to obtain
\begin{align}
x_1 &= 6 - 2x_3 - 4x_4 \\
x_2 &= -3 + x_3 + 6x_4
\end{align}

Note that you have two free variables, $x_3$ and $x_4$. You can choose any value for each of them and have a valid solution. Thus, rather than a unique solution you have infinitely many.

If I've misinterpreted $Q$ and your original RHS was a zero vector, then the specifics are a little different (three free variables rather than two, and the solved system would look a bit different), but you'd still have infinitely many solutions.